# Generics compilation error when using a Java Stream with a ternary "set" operator in the map method's lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

```java
package chap_10;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * 손님 이름 및 나이 정보를 위한 Customer 클래스 생성
 * 입장료는 1인당 5000원 고정
 * 20세 이상의 손님들에게만 입장료 부과( 그 외에는 무료 )
 */
public class _Quiz_10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

        customerList.add(new Customer("챈들러",50));
        customerList.add(new Customer("레이첼", 42));
        customerList.add(new Customer("모니카", 21));
        customerList.add(new Customer("벤자민", 18));
        customerList.add(new Customer("제임스", 5));

        System.out.println("미술관 입장료");
        System.out.println("==================");

        customerList.stream()
                .map(x->x.getAge()>=20 ? x.setName(x.getName() + " 5000원"):x.setName(x.getName()+ " 무료")) // error
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}

class Customer{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Customer(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

By using the conditional operator in the `map()` function, if the age is 20 or more, '5000 won' is attached to the end of the string, and otherwise, 'free' is tried, but an error occurs.

In the `Customer` class, setter and getter are used to compare the value using the ternary operator, and if it is true, a new string is inserted using `setName()`, but the following error appears.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image of text.

Comment: 1) The conditional operator is supposed to return a value. `setName` returns nothing. 2) `map` expects a lambda that returns a value. What do you expect that conditional operator to return?

Comment: Changing the return value from setName() from void to String solved the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here, it seems there is no need to use the `map` function instead you can iterate over the list using `forEach` in which you can update the attribute name of the object based on the condition and print the output as shown below:

**Code:**

```
customerList.forEach(x -> {
            if(x.getAge()>=20){
                x.setName(x.getName() + " 5000원");
            } else {
                x.setName(x.getName() + " 무료");
            }
            System.out.println(x);
    });
```

**Output:**

```
미술관 입장료
==================
Customer{name='챈들러 5000원', age=50}
Customer{name='레이첼 5000원', age=42}
Customer{name='모니카 5000원', age=21}
Customer{name='벤자민 무료', age=18}
Customer{name='제임스 무료', age=5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `map` when you want to change each value of the stream. This means that the lambda you put inside `map` must have a return type. In your case however, `setName` is a `void` function.

Using `map` is therefore not the correct function to use when you want to do side effects, like mutating a property. You could use the `.peek`-method instead for this, but in your case I would rather just use a normal for-loop. Streams are not really the tool for the job when you are only doing side-effecting operations.

With peek:

```java
customerList.stream()
    .peek(x -> x.getAge() >= 20 
        ? x.setName(x.getName() + " 5000원")
        : x.setName(x.getName() + " 무료"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

With a for-loop:

```java
for (var customer : customerList) {
    var newName = customer.getAge() >= 20 
        ? customer.getName() + " 5000원"
        : customer.getName() + " 무료";

    customer.setName(newName);
    System.out.println(customer);
}
```